# Windows Azure VM is freezing on copying files

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a VM with Windows 2012 R2 installed on it, and today I started experiencing file copy problems.

These are the cases:

File Copy;
If I try to copy a folder full of files to another location, the processing is frozen in a random file for some seconds or minutes.
This issue continues randomly untill all the files are copied.

Unzip:
The same as above. If I try to unzip a file, the process in frozen in a random file for some seconds or minutes.

Delete folder:
The same as Copy Files. If I try to delete a folder, it takes looong to start deleting, then the process in frozen in a random file for some seconds or minutes.

RDC:
If I copy from local machine to remote machine using Remote Desktop, the upload is done until the 99%, when the process is frozen for seconds or minutes.

It started to happen today, yesterday was working fine.

Is this a hardware problem? May the disk dying? Or a software problem?

I have even started the Windows Update, but after 30 minutes or so, the downloading contines (0 KB Total).

Any ideas?

Note: there are no errors on Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the VM File server drive is acting up. Are you seeing this for any other VMs that you have ? Silly question, **did you try restarting the VM ? May be some service is on a dead lock.**

May be there was a service issue during the time the issue was happening, you should be able to check the state here if it is still happening for your region the VM is present.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

If it is an expendable VM you can try reimaging it.

**If it still acting up, open a support ticket with Azure through the new portal,**

**To Open a Support Request**

- Go to the New Portal at https://portal.azure.com
- Browse to your VM that is causing the Problem.
- You should be able to see New Support Request on the Settings Blade of the VM.

[image: Image shows how to create a new support request]

Comment: I have checked the status yesterday, and they all were green. Well, today, everything is working fine again. Unfortunately I can't say if it was a momentary issue or the Windows Update has fixed something. :(

Comment: Thanks you for reporting back Cesar, Next time this happens please update the thread and we will take a look at it for you.